# How to select a week in calendar using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

My calendar code:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
 var events = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
      },
      defaultDate: new Date(),
       // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true,
      droppable: true,  // allow "more" link when too many events
      dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

        $("#successModal").modal("show");
        $("#eventDate").val(date.format());

      },
     events    : events
  });

  });

</script>
```

view page code:

```
<div id='calendar'></div></div>
```

These are the code how to select a week in this calendar using js. i have tired using some code but it is not working well

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Select entire week in fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011421/select-entire-week-in-fullcalendar)

Comment: This would be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011421/select-entire-week-in-fullcalendar

Comment: But that question is not answered

Comment: @Jacky a) it is answered, just the user edited his post instead of answering it. B) if it wasn’t answered, asking it again while that is open isn’t really effective

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to select whole week in calendar using jQuery

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <input type="week" value="@week" class="form-control" id="Week" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Week picker */
.datepicker-days > table > tbody > tr:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Add weekpicker
    $('#Week').datepicker({
       calendarWeeks: true,
       weekStart: 1
    });
});

$('#Week').on('changeDate', function (e) {
    var value = $("#Week").val();
    var year = moment().format('YYYY');
    var week = moment(e.date).format('WW');
    $("#Week").val(year + '-W' + week);
});
```